# Как сделать отравку файла пользователю в Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Я создаю форму, которая вызывается по кнопке с помощью Easy FanBox. Суть кнопки в том, чтобы посетитель оставил свои данные в форме и после нажатия "Отправить" получил pdf файл. Не понимаю как это сделать, в интернете находил решение только чтобы посетитель мог прикрепить свой файл, но это мне не нужно

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/pdf+Contact+Form+7/

Comment: @SeVlad Я ничего нужного не нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего кроме вот этого решения не нашёл, но оно подошло 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUGxjK65dHw